# Store microsoft speaker recognition api data on Azure cloud

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Microsoft speaker recognition api for identify and verification of users voice.
However everytime I refresh my page all the enrolled profiles are lost. And I need to enroll again using my voice.

You can refer this github code [Link to code](https://github.com/rposbo/speaker-recognition-api)

Everything is working fine. Is there any way to store it on azure cloud. Below is the function from the above link which stores profile id in an array:

```
  var Profile = class { constructor (name, profileId) { this.name = name; this.profileId = profileId;}};
  var VerificationProfile = class { constructor (name, profileId) { this.name = name; this.profileId = profileId; this.remainingEnrollments = 3}};
  var profileIds = [];
  var verificationProfile = new VerificationProfile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the profile IDs in memory. When you refresh the page that information is lost.

You need to store the IDs in something that persists across reloads. For example, [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: You can also fetch profile info with a [GET call](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c211e597ed22ec38f431).

Comment: ok. So here is what i have tried: I used the api and copy pasted the profile id in the array. Now, for some reason it generates different profile id for the same user after the refresh.

Comment: ok so  thats done. But I still need to convert that array into a sql database

Comment: As local storage is subject to clean up. Anyways thanks for help